# chrome.pageAction.show() isn't working in tabs.onCreated listener

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**background.js:**

```
 chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);//Doesn't work...icon is still grey

 });
```

This is part of the code from my extension. I want every new tab to show page action whenever it's created. Unfortunately, `chrome.pageAction.show()` doesn't work. Everytime I create a new tab, its icon is grayed out.

However to my surprise, if I call `chrome.pageAction.show()` from console, it works perfectly.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "show Page Action",
  "description": "show icon in all tabs",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "background.js"]
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_true.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pageAction API is URL-based so you need to use tabs.onUpdated, which is executed after onCreated and has different parameters:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
});
```

Don't forget to add `"tabs"` in [manifest.json's `"permissions"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions).

Comment: Thanks.Can you elaborate more on why onCreated  doesn't work?

Comment: A tab doesn't yet have an URL in onCreated event because a tab is not bound to a certain URL, it starts loading a few moments later and gets reported in onUpdated event. And since pageAction API is URL-based by design, it is initialized only when the tab URL is known, that is in onUpdated event with `changeInfo` that contains `url`.

Comment: why can't the permission be "activeTab" instead of "tabs"?

Comment: It certainly can be "activeTab" if that's sufficient for your workflow.